# Isomorphism between symmetric and upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, vector-space-isomorphism

Question: Determine if the vector spaces $V=S_{3}$, the $3\times3$ symmetric matrices, and $W=U_{3}$, the $3\times3$ upper triangular matrices, are isomorphic. If they are, give an explicit isomorphism $T: V \rightarrow W$.

Attempt: I've determined that they are isomorphic, since they both have dimension $6$. I'm just not sure what to try as an isomorphism. Since the proof that all vector spaces of equal dimension are isomorphic uses coordinate vectors, I'd guess that those are the easiest ones to construct.

Could I map $S_{3}$ to $R^{3}$ using the coordinate vector map, then use the inverse of the coordinate vector map to bring $R^{3}$ to $U_{3}$?

$F : S_{3} \rightarrow R^{3}$ and $G : R^{3} \rightarrow U_{3}$, so if $T=F \circ G$, then $T : S_{3} \rightarrow U_{3}$. Seem legit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis of the space of $W$ is
$$
\{E_{i,j}\}_{i<j}\cup \{E_{i,i}\}
$$

A basis of the space of $V$ is
$$
\{E_{i,j} + E_{j,i}\}_{i<j}\cup \{E_{i,i}\}
$$

Hence, let us define $T:V\to W$ such as $T$ is linear and
$$\begin{cases}
T(E_{i,j} + E_{j,i}) = E_{i,j} & (i<j)\\
T(E_{i,i}) = E_{i,i}
\end{cases}$$

It maps a basis to a basis, hence it is an isomorphism:

1. if $T(x) = 0$, then with $x = \sum_{i<j} x_{i,j}(E_{i,j} + E_{j,i})
   +\sum x_kE_{k,k},$
   $$
   0 = T(x) = \sum_{i<j} x_{i,j}E_{i,j}+\sum x_iE_{i,i}\\
   \implies  x_{i,j}=0, x_k =0
   $$for every $i<j, k$. Hence $T$ is into.
2. If $y=\sum_{i<j} y_{i,j}E_{i,j}+\sum y_iE_{i,i}$, $y=T(x)$ with
   $$
   y= \sum_{i<j} y_{i,j}(E_{i,j} + E_{j,i})
   +\sum y_kE_{k,k}
   $$hence $T$ is onto.

Comment: Very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: every symmetric matrix is a upper triangular matrix in which the entries have been reflected about the diagonal.

Full solution:

Your bases will be likely along the following lines:

For $S_3$: $$\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right], \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right],\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right], \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right], \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right], \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$$

Define your isomorphism by sending the above to the following matrices:

$$\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right], 
\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right],
\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right], 
\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right], 
\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right], 
\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right],$$
respectively.

This is more than likely your basis for $U_3$.

It should be rather clear that this is invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however we haven't covered the theorem that if a linear transformation maps a basis to a basis then it is an isomorphism. What's the formula for this transformation?

Comment: I'd recommend using whatever methods you use to show that any linear transformation is an isomorphism.

Comment: First, show that it is a bijection, and then show that it is a linear transformation.  These are relatively easy to see for the defined map

Comment: Yeah, the only thing we've learned that says a transformation is an isomorphism is if it's bijective and linear. Shouldn't be too difficult. Thanks for the tips

Comment: Not a problem, let me know if you get stuck on anything.

Comment: The problem is pretty much done. Conceptual question - if linear transformations are the same as matrices, then are isomorphisms the same as the invertible matrices?

Comment: You're definitely on the right track; linear transformation **between finite-dimensional vector spaces after bases have been selected for each vector space** are matrices.  But yes, with that caveat, invertible matrices are isomorphisms.

Comment: Interesting. This sort of thing makes me wonder if matrices are really just a convenient way to deal with tricky objects, e.g. transformations, rather than unique objects in their own right.

Comment: In a sense, yes.  I'm sure most would argue that the motivation for matrices is as a convenient way to represent linear transformations, rather than the normal way in which they are introduced.